# Creating a new columns from the results of groupby from another column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create new columns out of the unique values of one column with the count of the unique values as values assigned in the row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a",20],["a", 10],["b", 5],["c",10],
    ["b", 10],["a", 5],["c",5],["c",5]],
columns=["alp","min"])

In [4]: df                                                                      
Out[4]: 
  alp  min
0   a   20
1   a   10
2   b    5
3   c   10
4   b   10
5   a    5
6   c    5
7   c    5
```

I tried using `groupby` to get the values I want

```
In [8]: df.groupby('alp')['min'].count()                                        
Out[8]: 
alp
a    3
b    2
c    3
Name: min, dtype: int64
```

Now, I want to create columns out of that output.

```
   count_a count_b count_c
0    3        2      3
```

Is there any function to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Series name by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html), convert to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.groupby('alp')['min'].count().rename_axis(None).to_frame(0).T.add_prefix('count_')
print (df)

   count_a  count_b  count_c
0        3        2        3
```

Or create `DataFrame` per constructor:

```
s = df.groupby('alp')['min'].count()

df = pd.DataFrame([s.values], columns='count_' + s.index.values)
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! What does rename_axis(None) do?

Comment: @theSekyi - it remove `alp` string